# XCode 7 - _BSMachError (os/kern) invalid compatibility (20) after splitViewController.showDetailViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, ios9

BS error is right!

The title error seems to occur intermittently but always at the same call.

The call is:

```
splitViewController.showDetailViewController(vcToShow, sender: nil)
```

I'm not sure if it's related but I'm also debugging a problem where for some reason the `UIViewController` is showing but is showing behind my currently presented view (which is a modal). When I dismiss the modal I see the vcToShow view controller.

If anyone could answer either of these questions it would be appreciated but really I'm asking about the MachError since it seems this can be caused by many things. Tried clean and build, issue persists.

Thanks.